# Step by step process of using resource.resx files(created outside the project using class library) in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I am creating an application using mvc4. In my application i created the resource.resx file outside the project (but in one solution where my mvc application is also reside) in class library. I want to use the label name or validation message from resource.resx file. 
Like:-

```
public class xyz
{
    [Display(Name = "LBL_name", ResourceType = typeof(Resource.abcd.Resource1))]
    public string Name1 { get; set; }

}
```

"LBL_name" is specified in Resource1.resx file.  "Resource.abcd" is its custom tool namespace.

I added the reference of class library to my mvc application and set the properties of resource.resx as suggested in [this link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx).

But it gives the following error

```
Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed.
Type 'Resource.abcd.Resource1' is not public or does not contain a 
public static string property with the name 'LBL_name'.
```

I am not sure of using the resource.resx file correctly. Can someone guide me one this.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in the resource editor in VS and make sure the access modifier param is set to Public.